# Using htaccess redirect all files to another domain but exclude the root domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Recently, I want to restructure and redesign my website, my old website located at www.example.com, there are lots of blog posts under this domain, like:

```
www.example.com/post1
www.example.com/post2
www.example.com/post3
...
```

I can redirect all those posts to another sub domain points in another folder (not sub folder), (if I put all those posts in a sub folder, it will recursive the subfolder name) , anyway, it works for me by using the code below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://pre.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But there is one things I want to do is not redirect the main domain, only all the posts.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/ # the new blog
# I tried below
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://pre.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Is it possible I can do that? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://pre.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Here `.+` will match possible URI path but `/` (note that the path prefix is removed before testing the pattern).